# codeigniter ajax firebug shows 200 but display no results

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

I need a quick help. please help me to figure out the problem.

I have a client's project, that is in codeigniter framework.
my client need an auto complete on their site. i tried best to make it working. everything is ok i write the MVC according to the tutorial. 
but my script returns nothing

my view for auto complete

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->config->item('view_path');?>autocomplete/ui.theme.css" type="text/   css" media="all" />
    <script src="<?php echo $this->config->item('view_path');?>autocomplete/1.4.3.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $this->config->item('view_path');?>autocomplete/1.8.6.jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).ready( function() {
        $("#postcode").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: 
            function(req, add){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/lookup",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: req,
                    success:    
                    function(data){
                        if(data.response =="true"){
                            add(data.message);
                        }
                    },
                });
            },
        select: 
            function(event, ui) {
                $("#result").append(
                    "<li>"+ ui.item.value + "</li>"
                );                  
            },      
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My autocomplete controller is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Autocomplete extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('autocomplete');
}

function lookup(){
    // process posted form data (the requested items like province)
    $keyword = $this->input->post('term');
    $data['response'] = 'false'; //Set default response
    $query = $this->MAutocomplete->lookup($keyword); //Search DB
    if( ! empty($query) )
    {
        $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response
        $data['message'] = array(); //Create array
        foreach( $query as $row )
        {
            $data['message'][] = array( 
                                    'id'=>$row->PC_POST_CODE,
                                    'value' => $row->PC_TOWN.' '.$row->PC_POST_CODE,
                                    ''
                                 );  //Add a row to array
        }
    }
    if('IS_AJAX')
    {
        echo json_encode($data); //echo json string if ajax request

    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('autocomplete/index',$data); //Load html view of search results
    }
}
```

}

/* End of file autocomplete.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/autocomplete.php */

and Model is also same in example.

when i see in the console of fire bug i see this message but no result.

```
  http://yaashinii.com/maxsurge/tyrechangr/index.php/home/lookup  200 OK    3.28s
```

site link is you can visit.

```
  http://yaashinii.com/maxsurge/tyrechangr/
```

I also checks that when i use only a simpe ajax call then the same result as well. and even  when i change the controller method to show only the result let say i change the

```
   function lookup(){
     echo 'waheed'; exit;
   }
```

even then the same result

```
 http://yaashinii.com/maxsurge/tyrechangr/index.php/home/lookup  200 OK 3.28s
```

Please help me it is a new kind of issue i didn't understand why it is happend.

Comment: you can check the autocomplete functionality in get started area.

Comment: You have `"waheed"` output before your JSON, causing a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @Musa for your fast reply. but if i have waheed out it should be dispaly waheed string in console firebug, you can see in the console firebug link turn red status 200 ok but response is nothing.

Comment: I'm getting this error on your page: `GET http://yaashinii.com/maxsurge/tyrechangr/js/jquery-1.5.2.js 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: it is not an issue this file added three time. two files are missing. when you type in type in  `ENTER POSTCODE` are in the fire bug you can see the request is working but turns red with ok status but response is nothing

Comment: hi, i'm not understanding your code structure. like what is home/lookup what I see it should be Autocomplete/lookup. then why are you using in the ajax url base_url in echo the simply appending home/lookup. instead of base_url('home/lookup). then lastly have you check the IS_AJAX whether it's working or not??

Comment: `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/lookup"` home is the controller and lookup is its method. an autocomplete call. the actual problem was cross domain call.but now i have solve the problem, below is my answer how i solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

I am visiting this addrss `http://www.yaashinii.com/maxsurge/tyrechangr/` but i have define base url in config file of codeigniter as `http://yaashinii.com/maxsurge/tyrechangr/index.php/` therefor it becomes a cross domain. and ajax not allow a cross domain access. you can see that i am accessing with `www` and base url without `www`.